# Bulk insert from txt in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, collation

I need to do some bulk inserts in SQL Table from a txt file.

```
bulk insert [dbo].[TempSample]
from 'D:\sqls\sample.txt'
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
go
```

In the txt file I have descriptions like 'Hörsching'. After insert is made I found descriptions in my table like 'H÷rsching'. How can we deal with that ? The collation of the table is set to Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Comment: How is the file encoded? Have you tried using the `CODEPAGE` parameter to specify the file's encoding?

Comment: @Richard you have right... i modified the script with CODEPAGE = 'ACP' and it's worked. Thanks for the idea... coud you add the solution to accept it?

Comment: @Richard could you please add it as Answer ?

Comment: See the new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the file encoded?

Have you tried using the `CODEPAGE` parameter to specify the file's encoding?

Comment: I tried with CODEPAGE = 'ACP' and it's worked. Thanks!